# Xml Type ... is not declared, or is not a simple type

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

i'm getting the xml schema from Xero : https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI-Schemas

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XeroConnector.XmlSchemas." + selectedEndPoint.Schema + ".xsd");

            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
            }

            schemaSet.Add(schema);
```

The schema is embedded resource in the project. When I tried to do schemaSet.Add(schema); I always get "Type 'entityValidationStatus' is not declared, or is not a simple type". Below is my schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Items"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="BaseTypes.xsd" />

  <xs:element name="Items" nillable="true" type="ArrayOfItem" />

  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfItem">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item" nillable="true" type="Item" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Item">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ValidationErrors" type="ArrayOfValidationError" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Warnings" type="ArrayOfWarning" />

      <xs:element name="ItemID" type="uniqueIdentifier" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="PurchaseDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />

      <xs:element name="UpdatedDateUTC" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element name="SalesDetails" type="ItemPriceDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="PurchaseDetails" type="ItemPriceDetails" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />

      <xs:element name="Name" type="itemNameType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="IsTrackedAsInventory" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
      <xs:element name="InventoryAssetAccountCode" type="accountCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="TotalCostPool" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="QuantityOnHand" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="IsSold" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
      <xs:element name="IsPurchased" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />

    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="entityValidationStatus" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ItemPriceDetails">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ValidationErrors" type="ArrayOfValidationError" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Warnings" type="ArrayOfWarning" />

      <xs:element name="UnitPrice" type="itemPrice" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="TaxType" type="taxType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="AccountCode" type="accountCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="COGSAccountCode" type="accountCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />

    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="entityValidationStatus" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The schema is looking for a BaseTypes :  <xs:include schemaLocation="BaseTypes.xsd" />.  You can validate schema using following VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Select either XML File or XML Schema.  Then paste xml into view.  Error will show up in Error List like any compiler error.

Comment: This is strange, this schema works well for me, using [this file for BaseTypes.xsd](https://github.com/XeroAPI/XeroAPI-Schemas/blob/master/v2.00/BaseTypes.xsd). The include looks alright, too, both schemas having no target namespace. It seems specific to VS. Maybe what's missing is telling VS where to find BaseTypes.xsd?